# How to create a heatmap using values?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, heat-map

How do I create a 'heatmap' in QGIS based on the values of the different points?  I did do this once before with rainfall, but can't remember how!

Comment: Ok, I think I've found what I used last time - v.surf.idw.  The only problem is that the vector file imports into GRASS without the values.  Will still sort this out.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Heatmap plugin.  It is the icon with two yellow circles.  You can get to it by either right-clicking somewhere on your toolbar and select from the popup menu of plugins or you can go to Plugins -> Manage Plugins.

Comment: @Sylvester..Perfect ans..this works for me..thanks : )

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to create the heatmap in GRASS and seem to have found the solution.